# Complex equation with arg(z), but unknown on the form a+bi

Tags: complex-numbers

$z=(x+i)^2$, $x > 0$ and a real number, solve for $x$

$\arg(z)=\frac {\pi}3$

$w = \sqrt z$

$w = x+i = \sqrt{x^2+1}$ $\ e^\frac{i\pi}{6}$

Now I could solve the bottom equation, but there must be an easier way? How should I have rather solved this question?

Comment: What do you want to solve for??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$x+i=\sqrt{x^2+1}e^{i{\arctan\frac{1}{x}}},$$
then
$e^{i{\arctan\frac{1}{x}}}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}$ which implies
$$\arctan\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{6},$$
this gives you
$$x=\cot\frac{\pi}{6}=\sqrt 3.$$

Comment: Your $w$ is $w=\sqrt{3}+i $ then you can get $z=w^2$.

Comment: so $z=2+i2\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: thanks! man, glad to be helpful!